# JavaScript Validation For Checkbox, When Multiple checkbox selected from option list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox, listbox

I want to do JavaScript validation for Checkbox

If Value from Checkbox is not selected, it should get alert "Please Select Languages You Know"

But if user select 2 Languages from list of checkbox. I need that 2 languages should get alert using JavaScript.

I know to do with single checkbox, but not getting how to do using array.

Here is my Code...

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
function myFunction(form){
    
  var i,
  chks = document.getElementsByName('lang[]');
  
  for (i = 0; i < chks.length; i++){
    if (chks[i].checked){
        
      //Here how i should alert selected values 
        
        return true;
    }else{
        alert('No item selected');
        return false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
 <form name="registration" id="registration_form_id" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction(this)">

      <div id="languageId"><label>Language : </label>
                                                        
          <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="english" >English</input>
                                        
          <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="marathi">Marathi</input>   

           <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="hindi">Hindi</input> 
                                                    
      </div>

     <div id="submit1"><button type="submit">Submit</button></div><br/>

     </form>
```

Thank You,
Rahul

Comment: There is no code in your snippet, only html

Comment: yes there is no code in snippet.

Comment: if you want anyone to help you, show us what you've tried so far (script wise)

Comment: @Kooilnc - yes i added my script code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the list of selected checkbox values.. you can use this..

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    var values= [];
    $('#MyDiv input:checked').each(function() {
        values.push(this.val);
    });
    // now values contains all of the values of checked checkboxes
    // do something with it
});
```

Comment: I didn't notice a `jquery` tag in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one selected value, it's easier to use a `radio` input type. With it, you can find the selected value using a `querySelector` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)). For multiple languages, you can also use  `querySelectorAll`, convert its results to an `Array` and use `Array.map` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) to map the results into an `Array` of the values of the checked checkboxes.

Here's your snippet rewritten for both cases (without a form):

```js
(function (d, w, undefined) {
  d.querySelector('#languageId button').addEventListener('click', doSubmit);
  d.querySelector('#multiLanguageId button').addEventListener('click', doSubmitMulti);
  var languageSelectorContainer = d.querySelector('#languageId');
  var multiLanguageSelectorContainer = d.querySelector('#multiLanguageId');
  
  function doSubmit() {
    var languageChecked = languageSelectorContainer
                           .querySelector('[type=radio]:checked');
    d.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = 
                    'your selected language: <b>'+ 
                     (languageChecked 
                      ? languageChecked.value 
                      : 'not yet selected') +
                     '</b>';
  }
  
  
  function doSubmitMulti() {
    var languagesChecked = [].slice.call( 
                              multiLanguageSelectorContainer
                                .querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]:checked') )
                            .map(function (v){
                              return v.value;
                             });
    d.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = 
                    'you selected these language(s): <b>'+ 
                     (languagesChecked.length 
                      ? languagesChecked.join(', ') 
                      : 'none yet selected') +
                     '</b>';
  }
}(document, window))
```

```html
<div id="languageId">Pick your language:
  <input type="radio" name="lang[]" value="english">English
  <input type="radio" name="lang[]" value="marathi">Marathi
  <input type="radio" name="lang[]" value="hindi">Hindi
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="multiLanguageId">Pick the languages you know:
  <input type="checkbox" name="mlang[]" value="english">English
  <input type="checkbox" name="mlang[]" value="marathi">Marathi
  <input type="checkbox" name="mlang[]" value="hindi">Hindi
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```